# Apply a standard business code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Actually I have a handler like that

```
ko.bindingHandlers.setElementVisibility = {
    init : function ( element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext ) {
        var val = valueAccessor ( );
        if ( val !== undefined && val !== null && val !== '' ) {
            $ ( element ).addClass ( 'show' );
            return;
        }
        $ ( element ).attr ( 'class', 'hidden' );
    }
};
```

Then on the View I have

```
<span data-bind="text: Name, setElementVisibility: Name">
```

I would apply a check on all my observable vars into my ViewModel as it is now but without write a function into the View.
Is that possible?
May I extend the observable object?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Is your binding handler not working?  If so, could you explain what isn't working.

Comment: it works, I just asking if exist a better way to apply that automatically without type on the View the ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can use [**css**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding instead

```
<span data-bind="text: Name, css: Name() ? 'show' : 'hidden'"></span>
```

Also, you can combine two bindings to one:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showIfPresent = {
        init : function ( element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext ) {
            var val = valueAccessor();
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {text : val, css : val() ? 'show' : 'hidden'})
        }
    };
```

view

```
<span data-bind="showIfPresent : Name"></span>
```